# "vagrant box update" automatically before "vagrant up"

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to configure the Vagrantfile, so `vagrant box update` run automatically when the box is starting via `vagrant up`?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. It was exactly the same question I had when googling, and found the answer here I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible, as you can see in the Vagrant docs:

> Using the Vagrantfile, you can also configure Vagrant to automatically check for updates during any vagrant up. This is enabled by default, but can easily be disabled with config.vm.box_check_update = false in your Vagrantfile.
>
> When this is enabled, Vagrant will check for updates on every vagrant up, not just when the machine is being created from scratch, but also when it is resuming, starting after being halted, etc.
>
> If an update is found, Vagrant will output a warning to the user letting them know an update is available. That user can choose to ignore the warning for now, or can update the box by running vagrant box update.
>
> **Vagrant can not and does not automatically download the updated box and update the machine because boxes can be relatively large and updating the machine requires destroying it and recreating it, which can cause important data to be lost. Therefore, this process is manual to the extent that the user has to manually enter a command to do it**.

You can check more of the docs in this [link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html)